# rearrange UIIviews based on gestures

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uiview

I am building an iphone app that has multiple UIViews in a 3x3 matrix (so total of 9 UIViews) within one UIViewController. I am trying to find a way to let the user move one view to a location in the matrix which will then rearrange the rest of the views accordingly. Think of when you drag an app on your springboard to another place and all the other icons arrange themselves accordingly.

What is the best way to accomplish something like that?

Comment: Use `UIPanGestureRecognizer`, using the `translationInView` to adjust the coordinates of the item you're dragging. When you let go, you can use `UIView` class method `animateWithDuration` to animate the moving of various items to their final locations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`UIPanGestureRecognizer`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPanGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html), using the `translationInView` to adjust the coordinates of the item you're dragging. For a discussion of gesture recognizers, see the [Event Handling Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizers/GestureRecognizers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH6-SW1).

When you let go (i.e. the gesture ends), you can use `UIView` class method `animateWithDuration` to animate the moving of various items to their final locations.

So, in `viewDidLoad`, you might do something like the following (assuming that you had your nine controls in an array called `arrayOfViews`):

```
for (UIView *subview in self.arrayOfViews)
{
    UIPanGestureRecognizer *gesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self  
                                                                              action:@selector(movePiece:)];
    [subview addGestureRecognizer:gesture];
}
```

And then your gesture recognizer handler might look like:

```
- (void)movePiece:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    static CGPoint originalCenter;

    if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
    {
        originalCenter = gesture.view.center;
    }
    else if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
    {
        CGPoint translation = [gesture translationInView:self.view];

        gesture.view.center = CGPointMake(originalCenter.x + translation.x, originalCenter.y + translation.y);
    }
    else if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25
                         animations:^{

            // move your views to their final resting places here
        }];
    }
}
```

This is the bare-bones of what a dragging of controls around might look like.

Comment: +1...any idea how can i know the location of the UIView once I drag it somewhere?

Comment: You can look at the view's `center` or `frame` properties. And, anticipating the follow-up question of how do you know which one of the nine views that were moved, I think the easiest way is to set the `tag` integer property for each of the nine views as you're creating them (or setting them up in Interface Builder), giving each one a unique `tag` value. Then you could look at `gesture.view.tag` and you'd know which one you moved.

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing for iOS 6, definitely have a look at the [UICollectionView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html) class. If you have dealt with table views before the learning curve should not be too steep. You get the rearranging as well as all the animation for free.